# how can i include jsp page in html?

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans

I am using Netbeans and MySql server. I want to add JSP content into an HTML file. How can I include it?

Answer (score 7):

Make the HTML file a JSP page, and use a JSP include (static or dynamic, depending on what you want, but you probably want a static include here):

```
<%@include file="theJspToInclude.jsp" %>
```

HTML files are static resources that are served as is, without any kind of interpretation, by the web container.

Comment: the thing is that i want to keep the html file instead of jsp bcoz the jsp page creates a session which makes difficult to invalide taht session in next page so it will be good to keep html file and including jsp file in it,,so can i do it?

Comment: use <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" session="false" %> It will not create session

Answer (score 5):

JSP is a dynamic one. It needs a web container to get executed. Why do  you need to include it in a static html page. To my knowledge, if you want to include a jsp page in a html page, then your page is intended to be dynamic. So you have to change that to be a JSP page. Now you can use

```
<%@include file="includeable.jsp" %>
```

This will include your jsp.

You cannot include a JSP to a HTML page.